# Why will this timer not start in a .net service application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, timer

I have this code for a Windows service I am writing in .NET....However the TICK function never gets executed regardless of what interval I put in the tmrRun properties.  What am I missing?  I am sure its something stupid I am not seeing.

Thank You

```
    
Imports System.IO

Public Class HealthMonitor

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        // Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        // in motion so your service can do its work.
        tmrRun.Start()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        // Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
        tmrRun.Stop()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrRun_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrRun.Tick
        //DO some stuff
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You're going to need to give more information than that.  You don't define any of the code that sets up your timer (as in, how often it runs, etc..) and you don't tell us what kind of timer it is.

Comment: Could you show the initialize code for the timer? I don't see where you hook the timer tick event to your member function `tmrRun_Tick`

Answer (score 7):

This helps for me.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Timers

Public Class MyTimers

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

        Dim MyTimer As New System.Timers.Timer()
        AddHandler MyTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

        ' Set the Interval to 10 seconds (10000 milliseconds).
        MyTimer.Interval = 10000
        MyTimer.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using System.Windows.Forms.Timer that won't work in a service. Look into the other two times you can use in .NET.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bind your events properly.  You can use `System.Timers.Timer` and bind the `Elapsed` event to `tmrRun_Tick` before you start the timer.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) explains the different timers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached the eventhandler using AddHandler?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Windows.Form.Time and the Tick event of that, which is not going to work in a Windows Service.

You will have to System.Timers and the Elapsed event to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `AddHandler` to your `OnStart` sub.

Eg. :

```
Dim TimerX as new system.threading.timer
'You can also use
'Dim TimerX as new system.timers.timer
'And you can't use
'Dim TimerX As new system.windows.forms.timer
'As it is only available in forms

public sub onStart(ByVal args as ...)
AddHandler TimerX.Elapsed, AddressOf TimerX_Tick
With TimerX
.interval = 1000
.enabled = true
End With
end sub

private sub TimerX_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
'Tick
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

i've the same problem, but i'm using `System.Timers.Timer` and i've handled the `Elapsed` event ... working in some machines not in others.

I've found out that my custom logs was not working inside the timers, and the exceptions swallowed by the the task/thread the code was running in.

Use the windows event log (`System.Diagnostic.EventLog`) to be sure what's going on.
It's pretty easy.